# Triggering telegram bot command on user input

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a situation where I need to run a telegram command when user sends some message to the bot to open a menu from `telegraf-inline-menu`.

As this library offers a functionality to open that menu on some command like `menu.setCommand('start')` I thought it would be appropriate to just trigger command on `bot.hears()`.

#### In pseudo code

```
menuSetcommand('/test')

bot.hears(someRegex, ctx => {
triggerCommand('/test')
})
```

If this is not possible, some tips and directions for research are highly appreciated!